# How can I use a list comprehension to extend a list in python?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, nested, list-comprehension

I'm not experienced in Python, and I often write code that (simplified) looks like this:

```
accumulationList = []
for x in originalList:
    y = doSomething(x)
    accumulationList.append(y)
return accumulationList
```

Then after my test passes, I refactor to

```
return [doSomething(x) for x in originalList]
```

But suppose it turns out a little different, and my loop looks like this:

```
accumulationList = []
for x in originalList:
    y = doSomething(x)
    accumulationList.extend(y)
return accumulationList
```

where the `doSomething` list returns a list. What is the most Pythonic way to accomplish this? Obviously, the previous list comprehension would give a list of lists.

Comment: @chris_rands -- It seems a little odd to mark a question as a dupe 7.5 years after it was asked -- it doesn't serve the purpose of directing the OP to the duplicate, and the questions are not quite similar enough the merging is an option. /shrug

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Much simpler and cleaner with list comprehension:

```
[y for x in originalList for y in doSomething(x)]
```

Comment: Great improvement! Back when I asked the question, I wouldn't have though to use a nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this?

```
accumulationList = []
for x in originalList:
    accumulationList.extend(doSomething(x))
return accumulationList
```

or shorter code (but not optimal):

```
return sum((doSomething(x) for x in originalList), [])
```

or the same:

```
return sum(map(doSomething, originalList), [])
```

Thanks to @eyquem for the hint (if using Python 2.x):

```
import itertools as it

return sum(it.imap(doSomething, originalList), [])
```

Comment: ``return sum(map(doSomething, originalList)), [])`` better with **imap** if Python 2. Right if Python 3

Answer (score 3):

I think the answers involving add or iadd run in quadratic time, which probably isn't good.  I'd try:

```
from itertools import chain
accumulation_list = list(chain.from_iterable(doSomething(x) for x in originalList))
```

Answer (score 2):

Python's in-place add operator (`+=`, available as `iadd` in `operator` module) is equivalent of `.extend` for list. Pair it with `reduce` to get what you want.

```
import operator

reduce(operator.iadd, (doSomething(x) for x in originalList)
, accumulation_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is special syntax for this case. But you could make the for loop shorter:

```
accumulationList += doSomething(x)
```

If you insist, you could use functional programming to flatten the list:

```
result = reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, [[i,i*2] for i in range(3)])
```

But I wouldn't call this pythonic, I think it's harder to read than a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

[Functionally](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map). For an input list `L`:

```
res = list(chain.from_iterable(map(doSomething, L)))
```

If you need an iterator, simply remove the `list` call. Here's a demo:

```
def doSomething(value):
    return [value * i for i in range(1, 4)]

def original(originalList):
    accumulationList = []
    for x in originalList:
        y = doSomething(x)
        accumulationList.extend(y)
    return accumulationList

def new(L):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(map(doSomething, L)))

x = [1, 2, 3]

assert original(x) == new(x)

print(new(x))

[1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 3, 6, 9]
```