# Extend multiple elements in one line iteration

Tags: python, list, loops, iteration

For

`A=[1,2,3]`

I would like to get

`B=['r1','t1','r2','t2','r3','t3']`

I know it is easy to get `['r1','r2','r3']` by

`['r'+str(k) for k in A]`

How could I get B by one line loop as I showed above?

Many thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38400096/how-to-use-list-comprehension-with-extend-list-method, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947137/how-can-i-use-a-list-comprehension-to-extend-a-list-in-python, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44667519/python-how-to-extend-or-append-multiple-elements-in-list-comprehension-format

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a nested list comprehension.

```
>>> A=[1,2,3]                                                                                                                            
>>> [fmt.format(n) for n in A for fmt in ('r{}', 't{}')]                                                                                    
['r1', 't1', 'r2', 't2', 'r3', 't3']
```

Comment: I like the answer best! It is so clear! Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 9):

Use a [nested list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#nested-list-comprehensions):

```
A=[1,2,3]

B = [prefix + str(a) for a in A for prefix in 'rt']
```

Comment: It seems like two loops in a line! It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Using `itertools.product`

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product(*[[1,2,3],['r','t']]))
Out[20]: [(1, 'r'), (1, 't'), (2, 'r'), (2, 't'), (3, 'r'), (3, 't')]
[y +str(x) for x, y in list(itertools.product(*[[1, 2, 3], ['r', 't']]))]
Out[22]: ['r1', 't1', 'r2', 't2', 'r3', 't3']
```

Comment: I think you probably want `y + str(x)` but otherwise, good use of itertools

Comment: Is there some people given downvote for all answer here ? u'd better leave a reason

Comment: @Woody1193 thank you updated